# Edit file that requires sudo permissions from SSH client

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-4, sudo

I need to edit `/boot/config.txt` file from `WinScp` ssh client. In order to make changes in file I need root permissions for my login. As default pi does not have such permission and I don't have console in WinSCP in order to type sudo.

How to change file `/boot/config.txt` content from WinScp (or Notepad++) client?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a proper SSH client like **putty** to get a Secure SHell on the Raspberry Pi. There you can execute all commands, also **sudo**.

Comment: But I would like to use convenient Windows editor in order to edit file that requires permission.

Comment: @vico That isn't a problem belonging to Raspberry Pi. You should better asked at a MS Window$ forum.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you do not have any other users defined on the Pi.

Take the SD card out of the Pi and pop it into a Windows / Mac or Linux computer and edit it there.

The Pi OS does not come with the root user enabled so you cannot use that as the originator of the connection to work within the security.

Failing that, load a ssh client on your local computer.

Comment: Not necessarily a good idea because of the fact that Windoze routinely "breaks" text files due to their use of "CR-LF" line endings.

Comment: @Seamus  And MACs have a habit of changing quotes in the Apple provided GUI editor but does come with nano :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a competent text editor on your Windows machine, you will "break" RPi's `/boot/config.txt` file by editing it in Windows (i.e. editing with `Notepad`). Here's a [brief explanation](https://danielmiessler.com/study/crlf/) of this well-known and long-standing issue.

The solutions:

1. Use PuTTY instead of WinSCP ([@Ingo's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119258/83790)) so that you can edit the files in `nano` or one of the other text editors on the RPi.
2. If you insist on editing the files on Windows, get a text editor that supports Unix/Linux-style line endings. See [this Q&A for suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001900/which-text-editors-handle-both-windows-and-unix-style-line-breaks-properly)
3. Wrt all of the permissions business: I don't know how WinSCP does anything, but if RPi is blocking you from uploading a revised `/boot/config.txt` using WinSCP, then just remove the SD card & edit it IAW #1 above. The `boot` partition is FAT32, so in effect there are no permissions/controls.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally hard, if possible at all, to use `sudo` with SFTP (in any client not only in WinSCP).

But it's doable with some hacking.

The main thing is to run `sftp-server` via `sudo` in WinSCP [*SFTP server* session setting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp):

```
sudo /path/to/sftp-server
```

Though `sudo` may need some setup to allow this.

For more details, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo)